# Magento - Checkout page not loading https URL for catalogsearch

Tags: magento, ssl

I have just set up a Magento store and eveything is working fine, except for a problem in the catalog search URL.

When I go to the checkout page, everything is loaded in HTTPS, except for the catalog search URL, which makes chrome give a warning saying that there's mixed content in the page. When I check the source code, it says:

```
<form id="search_mini_form" action="http://XXXX/catalogsearch/result/" method="get">
```

But that only happens when the user is not logged in (or a first time customer). Once the user is logged in, the URL is loaded properly:

```
<form id="search_mini_form" action="https://XXXX/catalogsearch/result/" method="get">
```

Any idea on why this could be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537864/catalog-search-magento-not-working-https-ssl

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the complete solution, and I have no idea why this is happening also on my store - but a temporary "patch" would be to open:

**app/design/frontend/fogento/default/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml**

and manually modify the first line of the form element to use the secure url including https.

For example:

```
<form id="search_mini_form" action="https://www.yoursite.com/catalogsearch/result/" method="get">
```

This will give you the green address bar in chrome.