# Catalog Search Magento - Not working https/ssl

Tags: forms, magento, search, ssl, https

After updating my Magento site to https:// the catalog search function is no longer working.

I imagine this is because when submitting a search query the form is sending its request in http.

How can I ensure that the search form posts its information using HTTPS?

Comment: Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101751/magento-checkout-page-not-loading-https-url-for-catalogsearch

Answer (score 1):

As I debug this issue in more detail. I have found that in `catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml` template form post URL fetched from catalogsearch helper.

```
$this->helper('catalogsearch')->getResultUrl();
```

Below is the function definition:

```
public function getResultUrl($query = null)
{
    return $this->_getUrl('catalogsearch/result', array(
        '_query' => array(self::QUERY_VAR_NAME => $query),
        '_secure' => Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure()
    ));
}
```

So it will work on both secure and unsecure page.

You have to check how Form submit URL fetched in your current theme `catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml` template file.